# How does a computer boot up?

Tags: memory, kernel, bootloader, bios

I understand that the computer loads the first sector of memory known as BIOS, which runs diagnostics on hardware and the proceeds to load the OS.  I guess my question leans towards the hardware side.  How does the computer know which memory to boot from (RAM, ROM, FLASH, etc).  I understand the differences between memory and I understand computers boot from the hard drive, but Im attempting to make an 8 bit computer with a z80 microprocessor, which will need to boot from ROM or Flash memory.  The only problem is that the processor reads only from whatever memory the address pins are connected to and there are no separate address pins for ram and rom.  Its also impractical to run the system on rom or flash due to the much slower read/write time compared to ram.  The z80 to the best of my knowledge doesnt have separate commands for reading from rom and ram, and it wouldnt matter even if it did because the ram will be blank upon powering up.  How does a computer choose to read from rom only upon booting and then switch to ram once the OS has been loaded.  Is it hardwired in using logic gates?  And how does a computer choose to write to flash memory or a hard drive instead of ram once the OS has been loaded?  Would flash memory be treated as a device?  Or is this also hardwired into the motherboard using logic gates?  Sorry for giving so much background, I just dont want you to waste your time explaining things Ive already grasped.  Ive just researched this to a great extent and thought about it for hours on end and cant seem to figure it out, and everywhere Ive looked doesnt explain how the computer chooses which memory to read from, it just says that it does.  Thanks

Comment: Most processors start execution at the "reset address".  Instructions at that address stored in whatever memory that is installed/mapped there, are executed at startup.  Typically a modern CPU has a ROM installed at that reset address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm answering what you are asking, but I'll give it a try.

Some computers (at least, IBM PC-compatible computers), after powering up, usually run this BIOS (Basic Input/Output System) program. For this to happen, to the best of my knowledge, the hardware must make the jump to this code, and this code must be accessible (that is, mapped) from the physical memory, since that's where the CPU will execute code from. So, a physical address space with some read-only areas where this code is hard-wired to would do the trick.

Once the BIOS code is running, it can select how to proceed next. It can copy a sector from a hard disk to memory, (or a bunch of data from a Flash drive) and then jump to it, or whatever. That's up to the BIOS writer.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain the Pentium boot up process very briefly.

On the flash ROM mounted on the Motherboard. there is a small program called BIOS (basic input, output system). After pressing the power button the BIOS program is executed.
The BIOS contains low level software that performs the following operations :-

- checks how much RAM is installed and if all other PCI and ISA buses peripherals are connected.
- it checks if all IO devices are connected.
- scans a list of boot devices and selects the boot devices based on BIOS configurations setup earlier by the user.
  once the boot devices is selected. the first sector from the boot device is read into memory and executed. it contains a simple program which examines the partition table and selects the Active one (Holding the OS). The secondary bootloader is read from that partition. this loader then reads the OS from the partition into the memory and runs it. After running, the OS asks the BIOS for the configuration info for each device and configure the new devices (those have no stored configurations). after all devices configurations are set. they are delivered to the kernel. Then it initializes tables, background boot up processes and starts login program or GUI.